# Автоматическая очистка LOG-файла

Tags: логирование

Есть скрипт чата, все данные из этого чата сохраняются в лог-файл.
Как сделать автоматическую очистку этого лог-файла? Например поставить лимит и при достижении в нем 100 строк, удалять первую строку и т.д.

Comment: Используйте базу данных. удаление первой строки из файла слишком тяжелая операция потому как по факту приходится переписывать весь файл. Если записи в файле сделать фиксированной длины то его конечно можно будет использовать как кольцевой буфер. или вести два файла, первый закончился, пишем во второй, второй закончился, очищаем первый и начинаем писать его заново

Comment: А можно это организовать без базы данных, любой способ, главное что бы очищать лог-файл, но последние 100 записей оставались не тронутыми?

Comment: Ну я целых два способа вроде предложил, кольцевой файл и два файла которые пишутся по очереди. в любом случае - это все должен будет делать тот ваш скрипт который сейчас чат записывает

Comment: А вы не могли бы подсказать, как сделать такой кольцевой файл?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80  Делаете заголовок в файле с указанием текущей первой и последней записей.  и сами записи, думаю лучше фиксированной длины, иначе слишком сложно. И не забываете про совместный доступ к файлу, надо гарантировать что файл одновременно не пишут два процесса, т.е. использовать блокировки

Comment: Спасибо большое, попробую)

Comment: А возможно сделать что бы лог-файл очищался ежедневно в заданное время?

Comment: Под linux системами есть logrotate, он сейчас практически во всех дистрибутивах по умолчанию стоит, надо только ваш лог к нему в конфиг добавить

Comment: А при помощи Cron можно это сделать? Если да, то как, какую команду вписать? Спасибо

Comment: Можно и кроном. буквально `rm /путь/файл` что бы просто удалить. ну или `echo -n >/путь/файл` что бы сделать нулевой длины

Comment: @Mike Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваши комментарии в виде ответа.